# getting undefined when using wordpress post meta with underscore in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

i am using wordpress rest api v2 for getting data from my working wordpress website to angularjs application. all is working fine but when i want to use post meta like "_ait-item_item-data". its return me an error "undefined".

i am using his code to get post meta :

```
$scope.fieldOne = $scope.businessDetails.post_meta_fields._ait-item_item-data;
```

and i want to print:

```
{{fieldOne}}
```

i know that the problem with underscore and hyphen but how can i get the meta data with them ?

this is the error in console:

```
ReferenceError: item_item is not defined
at itemSingleCtrl.js:13
at angular.js:16170
at m.$eval (angular.js:17444)
at m.$digest (angular.js:17257)
at m.$apply (angular.js:17552)
at l (angular.js:11697)
at K (angular.js:11903)
at XMLHttpRequest.y.onload (angular.js:11836)
```

Comment: Add proper error, `undefined` is not an error. It's a value.

Comment: edited in my question.. please check it

Comment: That is because you can access a property like this `_ait-item_item-data"` directly. You have to do something like this `$scope.businessDetails.post_meta_fields["_ait-item_item-data"]`

Comment: its correct @VipinKumar add it to answer... and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your property contains `-` in it, you can't use dot notation to access its value. You have to access it like below

```
$scope.fieldOne = $scope.businessDetails.post_meta_fields["_ait-item_item-data‌​"]
```